# About traditional Bitcoin mining

Tags: bitcoind, solo-mining, miner-configuration, bitcoin.conf

I'm curious about traditional bitcoin mining, before pooling.  Did an older version of the bitcoin wallet found on sourceforge have a mining feature built in which worked on a simple macbook?  if so was this later removed in favor of pooling software?

From what I've read the traditional bitcoin wallet had a mining feature which could be used on a macbook, and I'm wondering if that code would still be possible to use, even if it never wins any bitcoin..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official Bitcoin full node software always had the mining feature built in, and will probably always have. If you have the line `gen=1` in your .conf file, then you will start confirming transactions when you open the wallet. Take a look at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin