# Using GPU mining with the Bitcoin Wallet

Tags: solo-mining, gpu-mining, cpu-mining, mining-software

After [asking this question about using the Bitcoin wallet to mine](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38863/about-traditional-bitcoin-mining), I am wondering how I can get my GPU involved with the mining work?

Is this possible? or this there other, non-pooling software that I can use to get the GPU of a macbook to perform blockchain validation (aka mining)?

Comment: It will probably take about 10000 years for you to find a block. Maybe 1000 years if you have a fast gaming computer and use the GPU. Mining at slow hashrate with no hope to ever find a block does not help anyone in any way. If you want to help the network without ASICs, then run a full node instead (bitcoin core).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your GPU to mine, but it is going to mostly be a waste of time and energy now that there is specialized hardware (ASICs) to mine.

You need a piece of software that will allow you to mine with your GPU. The miner built into Bitcoin Core is only for CPU mining.

Check out [this page on the wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_software). The exact software you choose will depend on a number of factors including what make of GPU you have, your OS, etc.

Comment: doesn't some mining at least make the network more secure/stable?

Comment: @erikvold: The effect is negligible, since ASICs are some thousands of times more efficient than GPUs.  Particularly notebook GPUs.  The cost to you in electricity and thermal wear and tear far exceeds the benefit.

Comment: @erikvold To add to this, if you want to contribute something meaningful to the network, consider running a full node 24/7 and contributing bandwidth!